# The `*ngFor` directive was used in the template, but neither the `NgFor` directive nor the `CommonModule` was imported

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular and I can't use the ngFor component. This is the error:

The `*ngFor` directive was used in the template, but neither the `NgFor` directive nor the `CommonModule` was imported. Use Angular's built-in control flow @for or make sure that either the `NgFor` directive or the `CommonModule` is included in the `@Component.imports` array of this component.

And this is the code:

```html
<h2>List</h2>

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let c of contacts">
        {{c.id}} - {{c.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you're using a standalone component, you should include CommonModule in the imports of the @Component decorator. example: `@Component(selector: 'my-comp',  imports: [CommonModule], ... )`.  Alternatively, you can use the [control flow syntax](https://angular.io/guide/control_flow#for-block---repeaters) instead of *ngFor.

Comment: Agreed with using `@for` instead of `*ngFor` in any new development, but you don't need to import the whole `CommonModule` if you want to stick with `*ngFor`; you can just import the `NgFor` directive itself: `@Component(selector: 'my-comp', imports: [NgFor], ...)` (with `import { NgFor } from '@angular/common'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Angular 17 with standalone components, things like ngFor need to be included in the `imports` array of your component.

e.g.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacts',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgFor],
  templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
  styleUrl: './contacts.component.scss'
})
```

But better to use the new control flow syntax:

```
<ul>
  @for (c of contacts; track c) {
    <li>{{c.id}} - {{c.name}}</li>
  }
</ul>
```